# send text to gmail via PHP form

Tags: php, gmail

I have a question about PHP.

I want to create a really simple page with only one function.

a text box, and a button to send it to my e-mail address.

**/ I don't really even get the concept of a .php file, or how to implement it to a html file (or do I just create a php file?)

I've been surfing on the web for a way, but quite can't get it.

If you can give me some advice on it, I'd really appreciate it.

I wrote the program, but won't send it to the address("itoyanlifelog@gmail.com").
I'm running it on MAMP, local server.

Comment: Welcome to SO! can you supply the you created?

Comment: You want to use the [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) function, or better yet SwiftMailer, and read http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php for an introduction. *Download* the manual, don't just skim it.

Comment: Wow... You should start off with some reading about how PHP works... And maybe some basics about HTML form creation and processing. Besides that, you can check [Google](http://www.google.es/search?num=20&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=WQ8&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=form+mail+php&oq=form+mail+php&aq=f&aqi=g-s3g-v7&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6300l6300l0l6506l1l1l0l0l0l0l171l171l0.1l1l0), right now, first search result points to a downloadable [solution](http://www.tectite.com/formmailpage.php). Also, bear in mind that you may need some sort of mail server. Not sure if bundled with MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

1. use php mail() function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
2. if you are on a local machine be sure that you *can* send emails from local. Take a look here: http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/PHP_mail_function

Comment: I wrote the code, but even if I set my own address, and set the smtp settings in the php.ini, it won't work.

Comment: can you add here a sample to see it? Maybe you did something wrong by mistake